# Select gridded data from input array python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Has anyone had experience using an array to select gridded data from an input array? If I have an array such as the following lat/long coordinates:

```
 x = np.array([[66.39, -58.74], [66.47, -58.83], [66.55, -58.93]])
```

and I want to select the nearest snc data from the following table format:

```
lat,       lon,       snc

53.45,     25.45,     80

66.20,    -57.45,     45

66.10,    -58.90,     75
```

Which numpy tool can I use to select the closest snc values with the coordinates in the input array?  Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: "select the closest snc values.." Closest to what?  It's unclear what you're asking.  Maybe giving a specific example would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a little unclear as to what you are asking, but if you have an array of longitude, latitude pairs and you want to find the closest values from gridded dataset you can use my approach below. This is a Python function I used to extract station data from a gridded dataset (rectangular data) where each station was a longitude-latitude pair. You can specify how many of the nearest points to your station you want to extract the indices for. Once you have the list of indices for surrounding points you can interpolate the values to your station.

```
def getStationIndices(longitude,latitude,st_lon,st_lat,numberOfPoints):
    """
    This is a function that takes longitude and latitude as
    decimal input, and returns the index values closest to
    the longitude and latitude. This is an iterative process for finding the best
    index pair. 
    """
    if st_lon<0: st_lon=st_lon+360.0; NEG=True
    else: NEG=False

    """Input longitude should go from 0-360"""
    longitude=np.where(longitude<0,longitude+360,longitude)
    distance = np.zeros((longitude.shape),dtype=np.float64)
    listd=[]

    """First, create a list of distances from the station of interest, while
    also save the matrix of distances that contains the info to get the index pair that the  distance of interest corresponds to"""
    for eta in range(len(latitude[:,0])): 
    for xi in range(len(latitude[0,:])):
        distance[eta,xi] = np.sqrt( (latitude[eta,xi]-st_lat)**2.0 + (longitude[eta, xi] - st_lon)**2.0 )
        listd.append(distance[eta,xi])
    listsIndexes=[]
    listd.sort()
    """Now find the closest point to the station. When that point is found, remove the
    closests pooint and find the next closests point, until you have found numberOfPoints
    closests to station.
    """
    for i in range(numberOfPoints):
        value=listd[0]
        itemindex=np.where(distance==value)
        listsIndexes.append(itemindex)
        listd.pop(0)

    print ''
    print '=====getStationIndices======'
    if NEG is True:
        print 'Looking for longitude [%3.3f] and latitude [%3.3f]'%(st_lon-360,st_lat)
    else:
        print 'Looking for longitude [%3.3f] and latitude [%3.3f]'%(st_lon,st_lat)
    print 'Result ===>'
    for i in range(numberOfPoints):
        print 'Found index pair in gridfile',listsIndexes[i]
        if NEG is True:
            print 'Index corresponds to longitude [%3.3f] and latitude [%3.3f]'%(longitude[listsIndexes[i][0],listsIndexes[i][1]]-360,latitude[listsIndexes[i][0],listsIndexes[i][1]])
       else:
           print 'Index corresponds to longitude [%3.3f] and latitude [%3.3f]'%(longitude[listsIndexes[i][0],listsIndexes[i][1]],latitude[listsIndexes[i][0],listsIndexes[i][1]])

    """
    We want to use data interpolated from the 4 surrounding points to get appropriate values at  station point.
    We do this by using relative weights determined by relative distance to total distance from all  4 points.
    """
    dis=[]
    for i in range(numberOfPoints):
        dis.append(np.sqrt( (latitude[listsIndexes[i][0],listsIndexes[i][1]]-st_lat)**2.0 + (longitude[listsIndexes[i][0],listsIndexes[i][1]] - st_lon)**2.0 ))

    return listsIndexes, dis
```

Here, `longitude` and `latitude` are 2D arrays containing geographical information for your rectangular grid that holds your data. If your data are 1-dimmensional (e.g. lat = 0-90N, lon = 0-360E) you can create 2D arrays using:

```
import numpy as np
lon=np.arange(0,360,1)
lat=np.arange(0,90,1)
longitude, latitude = np.meshgrid(lon,lat)
```

To use the function, these data have to be positive (0-360) or you have to edit the function. To call the method, provide your geographical location for your station (e.g. st_lon=30.0, st_lat=55.2) and call:

```
gridIndexes, dis = getStationIndices(longitude,latitude,st_lon,st_lat,numberOfPoints)
```

Here, `numberOfPoints` is the number of gridcells surrounding your `(st_lon,st_lat)` that you want to extract. Next you exctract the data from the gridcells you identified.

```
 for i in xrange(numberOfPoints): 
     latindex=int(gridIndexes[i][0])
     lonindex=int(gridIndexes[i][1])
     result = TEMP[time,latindex,lonindex]
```

Here, I assume that your data is stored in an array of dimension `(time,latitude,longitude)`. You can further use `dis` to weight your station data to do weighted interpolation. You can look for more information [here](https://github.com/trondkr/model2roms/blob/14a9d8a258baf64ec360b218dcc17cd39c429c50/IOstation.py) for how I use this. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much and this is exactly what may help me. However, I am still learning python so I am a bit unclear how to use this function with regards to where to include the input lat long coordinates (used as a guide to subset gridded data) and where the information from the gridded data is being selected. I am familiar with how to input data into arrays and query those arrays but I am having a problem figuring out the connection with using an array to extract information from a second data set. Would you please be able to provide a little more guidance on how your code is applied?

Comment: @user3275006 I have updated my answer and provided some more info

Comment: This is great. However, I am unable to find where I can even get the grd and IOverticalGrid modules. They aren't available for me so could this be something that was included in an older version of Python?

Comment: @user3275006 You don't need those modules for what you are doing. I would stick with the example above. But if you want to use the whole package those modules are available as part of a toolbox here: https://github.com/trondkr/model2roms. But remember that toolbox is created assuming that you have specific input file types. You can use it, but you will have to modify it for your input data if you want to extract station data. It may be easier to write your own code based on the example above.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, load your data into array (especially if this is going to be done multiple times):

```
lat,lon,snc = np.loadtxt('inputfile',unpack=True...)
```

Then find the (squared) distances:

```
R = ((x[:,0]-lat)**2 + (x[:,1]-lon)**2 * np.cos(x[:,0])**2 )
#note cos term; this may not be needed for you
```

and get the SNC:

```
snc[argmin(R)]
```